# Change Vimeo link to Vimeo embed jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have written (and sourced) some code to adapt a Vimeo link such as https://vimeo.com/0000000 to a Vimeo embed such as https://player.vimeo.com/video/0000000

However some Vimeo links have more than one block of numbers for instance https://vimeo.com/0000000/0000000.

Which my code turns in to: https://player.vimeo.com/video/0000000. (with /video/ and without the two sets of numbers)

Is there a better method to adapt my code to account for both these scenarios.

```
//split vimeo ref from existing link
var url = $('.tour').attr('href');
var parts = url.split("/");
var last_part = parts[parts.length-1];

//add address to viemo embed link
$(".embedlink").attr('src', function(index, attr) {
return attr + (attr.indexOf('?') >=0 ? '&' : '') + last_part;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your link into parts like you do so far to get:

```
[
  "https:",
  "",
  "vimeo.com",
  "0000000",
  "0000000"
]
```

**First 3 parts are always the same** so delete them with splice:

```
parts.splice(0, 3);
```

to get:

```
[
  "0000000",
  "0000000"
]
```

Now join all parts left, no matter how many of them back into string:

```
parts=parts.join("/");
0000000/0000000
```

And now just use that to make new link:

```
"https://player.vimeo.com/video/"+parts
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
//split vimeo ref from existing link
var url = $('.tour').attr('href');
var parts = url.split("/");
console.log(parts);
parts.splice(0, 3);
parts=parts.join("/");
console.log(parts);

document.getElementById("newlink").innerHTML = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/"+parts;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tour" href="https://vimeo.com/0000000/0000000">https://vimeo.com/0000000/0000000</a>
<br>
<div id="newlink"></div>
```

Comment: @alib0ng0 "however the anomaly links don't have /video in" nether did I make such example nor solution.  I dont understand where this is coming from.

Comment: Your solution works for https://player.vimeo.com/00000/00000 but not https://player.vimeo.com/video/00000 - one has to have /video/ in the other must not

Comment: @alib0ng0 Your question is not that, you given a scenario: where "normal" link should be converted into player link no matter how many parts there is. Normal link is not a `player.vimeo.com/video/00000` . That is player link that should be a result and not converted from. I have read the question over and over and still dont see where player link needs to be converted into player link again for some reason?

Comment: I have updated the question, apologies if it wasn't clear, it's been a long day. Basically I have to account for both scenarios.

Comment: @alib0ng0 No problems, I am looking at your edits but I am still confused. You are saying if there is two blocks on original link one of the blocks needs to become video?  **You should just make a example list of original links, and list of desired result from those links, line by line. And cover ALL possibility**, cose this is just confusing. Im sorry. Im sure there is simple solution, I just don't understated how my answer is still wrong.

Comment: @alib0ng0 Make a list: `org_link ---> new_link`, line by line and cover all basis. It will make things much easier.